# Keycloak external user store with internal credentials

Tags: java, keycloak

Up until now, we've mirrored users from the Keycloak database to our custom user store. Nevertheless, we desire to solely keep users in the custom user store. Hence, I have implemented a `UserStorageProvider` in Java that integrates Keycloak with the custom user store. It does well in querying, adding and removing users. However, Keycloak should continue to manage user credentials. This means that while the user ID, username, and email will be fetched from the custom user store, user credentials should still be authenticated against the Keycloak database.

I'm aware of the `CredentialInputUpdater` and `CredentialInputValidator` interfaces. Unfortunately, all examples that I found, such as this [Keycloak Quickstart](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/user-storage-jpa), assume that the credentials are also held in the external store. How can I get Keycloak to authenticate externally managed users against internally managed credentials (in the `credential` table)?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the CredentialInputValidator interface and the keycloak with not try to validate in your User Provider, just in the internal credential.

With the CredentialInputValidator
[image]

Without the CredentialInputValidator
[image]